# Group boxplot data while keeping their individual X axis labels in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am plotting the Rank of Gene1 count (y-axis) against the Type of sample (x-axis). I wish to group the Type of samples according to their tissue of origin (Breast, Colorectum, Lung) and color-code whether they come from Cancer or Normal Tissue with Red and Green colour, respectively.

I produced the graph 1) BOXPLOTS WITH FACETS (please see below), which is close to my vision but shows some major issues. I have a few questions to improve on the graph:

[IMG]http://i57.tinypic.com/10yfmmw.png[/IMG]

**1)** Each facet ended up with 9 lanes (columns) from which many are not occupied by a box. How do I remove the lanes (columns) not occupied by the box in each facet?

**2)** Can I plot this graph without using the facets while still retaining the grouping as shown on the figure?

**3)** Is it possible to create the two layers of facet labels? I.e. I would like to place label "Gene1" above and across the existing facet labels. This would enable me to produce the same graph as shown below for the Gene2 so I could facet both graphs next to each other with "master" facet label on the top of each graph.

I hope this makes sense. Thank you everyone for your suggestions and ideas.

Please see the following code which will enable you to download my data and reproduce the graph:

**TEST FILE IMPORT**

```
fileURL <- "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4098921/testfile.csv"
test <- read.csv(fileURL,header=T)
head(test)


> head(test)
  Subset Tissue        Type id Gene1 Gene2
1 Normal Breast GTEx_Breast  1  5027 12597
2 Normal Breast GTEx_Breast  2  5287 12338
3 Normal Breast GTEx_Breast  3  2385 12543
4 Normal Breast GTEx_Breast  4  3174 12266
5 Normal Breast GTEx_Breast  5  6593 11350
6 Normal Breast GTEx_Breast  6  4648 10932
```

**1) BOXPLOT WITH FACETS**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test,aes(x=Type, y=Gene1, fill=Subset))+
geom_boxplot(notch=T, notchwidth=0.5,outlier.shape=1,outlier.size=2, coef=1.5)+
theme(axis.text=element_text(color="black"))+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.4))+
theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())+
labs(size= "Type",x = "",y = "Rank of Gene1 count", title = "1) BOXPLOT WITH FACETS")+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","lawngreen"),name="Subset",
labels=c("Cancer (TCGA)", "Normal (GTEx)"))+
facet_grid(~Tissue)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the non-used labels on the x-axis by adding the `scales = "free_x"` to `facet_grid`. If you also add `space = "free"` you will get boxplots of equal size. With:

```
ggplot(test,aes(x=Type, y=Gene1, fill=Subset))+
  geom_boxplot(notch=T, notchwidth=0.5,outlier.shape=1,outlier.size=2, coef=1.5)+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.4))+
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())+
  labs(size= "Type",x = "",y = "Rank of Gene1 count", title = "1) BOXPLOT WITH FACETS")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","lawngreen"),name="Subset",
                    labels=c("Cancer (TCGA)", "Normal (GTEx)"))+
  facet_grid(~Tissue, scales = "free_x", space = "free")
```

you will get the following plot:

[image]

When you don't want to use facet but keep the grouping, you might want to create a new variable that takes the grouping into account. you can do that with `interaction`:

```
# create the new variable
test$newType <- factor(interaction(test$Tissue,test$Type))
# set the correct order of the new variable
test$newType <- factor(test$newType,
                       levels=levels(test$newType)[order(levels(test$newType))],
                       labels=levels(test$Type)[order(levels(test$newType))])
```

Then you can make a new plot with:

```
ggplot(test,aes(x=newType, y=Gene1, fill=Subset))+
  geom_boxplot(notch=T, notchwidth=0.5,outlier.shape=1,outlier.size=2, coef=1.5)+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.4))+
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())+
  labs(size= "Type",x = "",y = "Rank of Gene1 count", title = "1) BOXPLOT WITH FACETS")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","lawngreen"),name="Subset",
                    labels=c("Cancer (TCGA)", "Normal (GTEx)"))
```

which produces the following plot:

[image]

If you want include both `Gene1` and `Gene2` in your plot, the best thing to do is first reshape your data to long format:

```
library(tidyr)
test2 <- test %>% gather(gene,value,5:6)
```

The you can make a plot with:

```
ggplot(test2,aes(x=Type, y=value, fill=Subset))+
  geom_boxplot(notch=T, notchwidth=0.5,outlier.shape=1,outlier.size=2, coef=1.5)+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.4))+
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())+
  labs(size= "Type",x = "",y = "Rank of Gene1 count", title = "1) BOXPLOT WITH FACETS")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","lawngreen"),name="Subset",
                    labels=c("Cancer (TCGA)", "Normal (GTEx)"))+
  facet_grid(gene~Tissue, scales = "free_x", space = "free")
```

Above code will give you the following plot:

[image]

An option to include the different Gene's without using an additional facet layer, you can use:

```
ggplot(test2,aes(x=Type, y=value, fill=Subset, alpha=gene))+
  geom_boxplot(notch=T, notchwidth=0.5,outlier.shape=1,outlier.size=2, coef=1.5)+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.4))+
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())+
  labs(size= "Type",x = "",y = "Rank of Gene count", title = "BOXPLOT WITH FACETS")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","lawngreen"),name="Subset",
                    labels=c("Cancer (TCGA)", "Normal (GTEx)"))+
  facet_grid(.~Tissue, scales = "free_x", space = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, hjust=1))
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution! Fantastic.

Comment: I know about the interaction function but what annoys me is that the X-axis labels gets very long. However, this graph makes it difficult to visualise the three tissues. Is there a way to place the bars of each tissue tightly together and leave a large gap between the individual tissue types?

Comment: Thank you h3rm4n, you helped me a lot! Now I just wonder if its possible to make the bars in each facet sitting tightly next to each other to save width. I will probablzy need to place Gene2 on the right of Gene1 since its difficult to compare the ranks:(

Comment: @Peter I've added another option.

Comment: Wau, this looks great! But sadly, it is not apparent fom the legend what is Gene1 and what is Gene2. They both look white and one has to make an assumption:( It is a pity that ggplot2 cannot plot hatched bars (at least according to my research).

Comment: But it might be doable by substituting `alpha=gene` in the first line with `color=line`. That would make differential color for the box outline if I am correct. Maybe the Genes can be differentiated by dashed vs solid lines? Not sure hos to do that though...